# how can i use one vendor directory for 5 different laravel 5.1 projects

Tags: php, laravel, vendor

I have  **5 different Laravel 5.1** projects. How can I use **one vendor directory for all projects**. Any suggetions?

Comment: what is real reason for that?

Comment: Saving server space.

Comment: @Straven Easier to manage? Prevents duplication of files? Saves hard disk space?  Does it matter?

Comment: It's going to offtop. I think it's not right way to use one vendor dir because if we have error on one of projects with one of packages we lost normal working of all projects, not one in which error occured.

Comment: How much space is occupied by the `vendor` directory currently? if it is only a couple of hundred MB then i suggest the maintenance issues are not worth the hassle of keeping track of differences in the `vendor` directory across the difference projects.

Answer (score 0):

Insert in composer.json:

```
"config": {
        "vendor-dir": "plugins"
    }
```

and change in `bootstrap/autoload.php`

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

to directory where You setup vendor dir.

Comment: I have tried it and spent couple of hours but not working. I think i have to keep different vendor dir's for all project!

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me :

I use a vendor directory for each project that contains only autoload.php file. At this file, I added a line, storing the location of the application's directory, eg `$GLOBALS['mydir'] = 'absolute path to project';`         and I modified the require_once statement, changing the path, pointing to the common vendor directory.

At the common vendor directory, I modified the vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php and added the line `$appDir =$GLOBALS['mydir'];` before the return array.

I replaced all $baseDir with the $appDir where /app/ exists at paths (for me there were 23 replacements).

Please note that in my case I have not updated my 5.1 Laravel. After update I think that the same must be done to autoload_static.php.
One good reason to use only one vendor directory, is that some host plans have a limit for the files per hosting account and vendor has more than 6000 files.